# Center a hyperlink inside li element in navigation bar

Tags: css, hyperlink, navigation

I want to create a navigation bar where the text is centered, but my CSS code places the hyperlink at the top corner of the li as seen in the image.

[image: demonstration of left/top aligned navigation text]

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 6%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#navigation  a {
    height: 10%;
    width: 50px;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: bold;
}

li {
    border-top: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-left: solid;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-left: 1px;
    height: 51px;
    width: 18%;
    background-image: url('../images/tab-selected.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x-y;
    border-color: #F0F0F0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li ><a href="overview.asp">overview</a></li>
    <li ><a href="overview.asp">overview</a></li>
 </ul>  
</nav>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too please. And do you want the text centered horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: I added the HTML, i want it centered both horizontally and vertically. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of vertically center something.

If you KNOW the words of the links and know they will not have a line break, you can add `line-height:51px;` to the anchor (which is the same height of the LI).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vMLpL/

---

*By the way, tips for you:*

- For the border, you can use `border:1px solid #f0f0f0;` then just give none to bottom, like `border-bottom:none;` instead of declaring all sides.
- When you want a BG to repeat both X and Y, the `background-repeat` is `repeat` only, not `repeat-x-y`.
- For the `vertical-align`, there is no `center`. It's `top`, `middle`, `bottom` and `baseline`. But it work only for inline elements regard to other inline elements besides or for `display:table-cell` elements (which will work like a td's `valign="middle"` atribute).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove the following from your "li" selector:

   - `height: 51px;`
2. Add the following to your "li" selector:

   - `text-align: center;`
   - `line-height: 51px;`